# Merge returning matrix of size x^2

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two sf objects, one with 7 columns and 1273 rows, the other with 2 columns and 1273 rows that is returned from a function applied to the first object.

I'm just trying to join the small dataframe to the large using the index number but when I use `merge(a,b)` it returns a dataframe with 8 columns and 1620529 rows, which is 1273^2.

the docs for merge make it sound like it usually figures out the right values to merge on, how do I specify that the index values are common to both dataframes?

Comment: It looks for columns that have the same name. If the names are different use the `by=` parameter. See the `?merge` help page.

Comment: yup, i'm aware of the by parameter, can I specify by index though? That doesn't have a name that I can see with names()

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: honestly, if i could reproduce this on purpose I probably wouldn't need help with the merge function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are merging by index try this:

```
 df_new<-merge(df1, df2, by=0, all=TRUE) # merge by row names (by=0 or by="row.names")
```

Comment: interesting because my understanding was that R is 1 indexed. that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley It is 1 indexed.  That has nothing to do with indexing though. It's just the convention for that particular parameter that the author of that function decided to use.  Per the help file for merge: "Columns to merge on can be specified by name, number or by a logical vector: the name 'row.names' or the number 0 specifies the row names. If specified by name it must correspond uniquely to a named column in the input."  So this really is assuming that you basically just want to paste the two data.frames together.  And if that's the case you could also use `cbind(df1, df2)`